# On Android, int is passed as null to database

Tags: android, codenameone

It seems like on Android, integers are passed as null to the database when used as parameter to a prepared statement, e.g. in

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO keycounter (key, counter) VALUES (?, ?)", key, counter);
```

In the simulator, this statement works fine when counter is an Integer and when counter is a String.

On Android, it fails with a NULL constraint violation when counter is an Integer, but it works fine when counter is a String.

This issue can be replicated with the form below.

Kind regards, Frans

```
import com.codename1.db.Database;
import com.codename1.ui.Button;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.Label;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BoxLayout;

public class DatabaseIntAsNullForm extends Form
{
    public DatabaseIntAsNullForm()
    {
        super("int is passed as null to db", BoxLayout.y());
        Button passInt = new Button("Pass int");
        passInt.addActionListener(e -> test("key", 1));
        add(passInt);
        Button passStr = new Button("Pass String");
        passStr.addActionListener(e -> test("key", String.valueOf(1)));
        add(passStr);
    }

    private void test(String key, Object counter)
    {
        try
        {
            Database db = Database.openOrCreate("IntAsNull");
            try
            {
                db.execute("CREATE TABLE keycounter (key TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, counter INTEGER NOT NULL)");
                try
                {
                    db.execute("INSERT INTO keycounter (key, counter) VALUES (?, ?)", key, counter);
                }
                finally
                {
                    db.execute("DROP TABLE keycounter");
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                db.close();
            }
            add(new Label("Success"));
            revalidate();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            add(new Label(e.toString()));
            revalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: probably because it is passed as `Object`, not as `int` or `Integer`

Comment: It is passed as a boxed int, i.e. as an Integer. Just to make sure, I also directly passed new Integer(1) and this made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the Android implementation of the execute method. This is fixed in the git commit here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/77c9ad1b9ecf107cb49bbfb95ebe31ecc09235a8

It will be available in the update this Friday (December 7th 2018).

Comment: Thanks! The workaround was easy, but it took some time to find it :-)